# CDK Route53 add 'A' record without deleting previously created record

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

```
new route53.ARecord(this, `CDNARecord${host}`, {
  zone,
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new route53Targets.CloudFrontTarget(cf)),
  recordName: host
});
```

The above code deletes previous 'A' record created by same stack.

I am not able to find a way with CDK Route53 by which previously created 'A' record is preserved. Please help with a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS CDK and AWS CloudFormation identify the representation of resources by logical ids. In the case of AWS CDK, the second argument to a construct is typically the id. The id must be unique within the scope i.e. typically within `this`.

When an AWS CDK runs it produces a Cloudformation template. If there was a resource with a logical id in a previous Cloudformation deployment, and in the current deployment the logical id is gone, Cloudformation will delete the resource.

In most cases, if you want to preserve the A record, or any resource for that matter, make sure the id of the construct stays as is.

Comment: I tried (somehow) keeping the logical ID - then it complains that the 'A' record already exists and the stack fails and does rollback!

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Somehow when I moved the Route53 stuff to it's own stack, it worked as expected. Thanks for your help and suggestion.